# Which is the best approach to get the sitecore item on ajax call

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

Think about the scenario, where the page has to render the content dynamically when they do some operation on page.

Here basically, page will contain a list of rendering and in each rendering we will be able to get the current item using below statement.

```
 var item = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item;
```

Now if i have to show the content on button click, we will do a ajax call to our mvc controller/action, and in our Action we can render the item by following statements.

```
Item item = SitecoreHelper.GetSCDb().GetItem("{item id}");
```

or

```
Item item = SitecoreHelper.GetSCDb().GetItem("item path");
```

But in both the cases we have to hardcode the id/path.

So can anyone tell me, is there any better approach to do this.

I appreciate your help.

Cheers:)

Comment: Why don't you send the current item id as parameter through your AJAX call?

Comment: @Ahmed : I have two question now.
1. How i will get the current item id? Where it will be stored?
2. If i wanted to access different item than the current item, how i can do that?

Comment: 1) In one of your rendering, you can store current item ID in hidden input for example, then using javascript you can get the value of the hidden item and send it through AJAX
2) Can you clarify more?

Comment: 2) The item i want to render during ajax call is different than the item which i rendered during pageload. For example: During pageload i have set my rendering item as content/Home/Item1, but during Ajax call i want to render content/Home/Item2.

Comment: You can still store Item2 ID in hidden input and send it over AJAX call, same as previous solution

Answer (score 0):

Something I've done on Sitecore + MVC projects was for content items that are going to be accessed by both Page Editor and by AJAX calls in JavaScript, is creating a new device in that items template _StandardValues, in that I set the query to ?Ajax=true. I then put only the HTML piece (without styles, and JS) as the layout. While the desktop view has what it would look like "after" it's been called by AJAX. This doesn't need any .net coding, it's all done via sitecore.

Comment: Could you please share some code snippet or screen shot of it.